# Test hypothesis "This profit is significantly different than the average"

Tags: hypothesis-testing, finance

I am writing a paper about Algo-trading and my supervisor asked me to test the hypothesis that "the return of the trading strategy is significantly different than the average".

To reach this result, it has been implemented a software doing the following:

1. Compute the profit by trading on a certain stock for a certain period of time according to the pre-set trading rules;
2. Generate a big sample (1,000) of "random trading strategies". For reaching this, it has been implemented a Linear Congruential Generator which is returning random numbers between 0 and 1; these numbers are hence used, over the same stock and over the same time-period, to decide if trading or not and then compute the profit of each trading session.

The output looks like follows:

[image]

I've studied statistics long time ago so, even if I've realized myself this question is very basic, I'm not able to remind.... how can I say if the profit 12.96% got by applying the trading rules is significantly different from the sample mean 13.05% of 10,000 trading sessions randomly executed?

**EDIT:** Any further suggestion about the sample-size or other factors might make the statistics more valid would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Given this evidence that on the average a *random* strategy performs better than yours, is there any need to consider your strategy further?

Comment: @whuber Of course no, there's no need. But the problem is that this is a very specific output (on a particular currency, on a particular time-frame, with a particularly simplified set of trading rules). So, what I'd like to understand is how could I "standardly compute" a significancy test to be displayed into the output, for all the times the profit will be larger than the average. That's the interesting point for the person believing his strategy is winning, isn't it?

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. It's still not clear to me how relevant any measure of "significance" would be in this context. What a person really wants to know about their strategy are two completely separate things: how well will it perform compared to available alternatives and how risky is it compared to those alternatives. "Significance" is a measure of the evidence one has concerning the former two things, so I grant it could be of interest, but how interesting is a comparison to *random* strategies going to be? Why would that be relevant to an investor?

Comment: The reason is pretty much the following: by applying a certain set of rules I enter and exit trades deciding to take a position...

Comment: if I took it well, I will earn.. and vice versa. It's approximately the same of tossing a coin, 50% of times I'll be lucky and the other 50% I'll be not. So, it's of interest to see if the profit got with the trading strategy is actually a "solid" profit or it's just a coin which has been tossed into the lucky side. Of course risk is important as well, but for that there's another measure that is tested against a random distribution. If it's more clear now, how would you test this hypothesis practically? If not, please let me know (I'll be glad to explain better)